# Extract value from JSON data of a pandas column with condition apply

Tags: python, pandas

Need to extract value from a json string stored in pandas column and assign it to a column with a conditional apply to rows with `null` values only.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [06010, np.nan, 06020, np.nan],
                   'json_col': [{'Id': '060',
                                 'Date': '20210908',
                                 'value': {'Id': '060',
                                           'Code': '06037'}
                                 },
                                 {'Id': '061',
                                 'Date': '20210908',
                                 'value': {'Id': '060',
                                           'Code': '06038'}
                                 },
                                 {'Id': '062',
                                 'Date': '20210908',
                                 'value': {'Id': '060',
                                           'Code': '06039'}
                                 },
                                 {'Id': '063',
                                 'Date': '20210908',
                                 'value': {'Id': '060',
                                           'Code': '06040'}
                                 }],
                })
                         

# Check for null condition and extract Code from json string

df['Col1'] = df[df['Col1'].isnull()].apply(lambda x : [x['json_col'][i]['value']['Code'] for i in x])
```

Expected result:

```
Col1

06010
06038
06020
06040
```

Comment: for performance reasons, it is better if you preprocess the json data into flat form before creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

To extract field from a dictionary column, you can use `.str` accessor. For instance, to extract `json_col -> value -> code` you can use `df.json_col.str['value'].str['Code']`. And then use `fillna` to replace `nan` in `col1`:

```
df.col1.fillna(df.json_col.str['value'].str['Code'])

0    06010
1    06038
2    06020
3    06040
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working for me. Doesn't throw any errors, but it isn't assign values either.

Comment: You can just assign it to a column with: `df['col1'] = df.col1.fillna(df.json_col.str['value'].str['Code'])`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
>>> df['col1'].fillna(df['json_col'].map(lambda x: x['value']['Code']))
0    06010
1    06038
2    06020
3    06040
Name: col1, dtype: object
>>>
```